# Trying to use c# to convert/pass data between two systems

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass data between two systems using C#. Each system is able to read/write data as a single string, but the formats do not match.

I'm trying to use this as a basis:

```
string convert(string inputString, int columnCount)
```

The inputString is supposed to be comma delimited string of values, and columnCount is expected to be the number of columns to group together.

```
convert("one, two, three, four, five, six",3)
```

to be able to return

```
"[[one, two, three],[four, five, six]]"
```

I have tried to create a test application to try to get it working, by creating two text boxes, one for the inputString, and one for the columnCount. With a label output and a button to test it. But I can't seem to get it to work.

```
string inputString = txtNumbers.Text;
int columnCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtColumn.Text);
string lblOutput = string convert(string inputString, int columnCount);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `convert("one, two, three, four, five, six",3)` have to return `[[one, two, three],[four, five, six]]`? On the first look, you have to return 3 columns instead of 2: `[[one, two], [three,four], [five, six]]`

Comment: Did you write any code at all other than the two boxes etc.?

Comment: By the way your values are not comma separated, they are "comma and space separated" is this correct?

Comment: @MaciejLos "number of columns to group together" sounds like count of items per group to me, which is what he's got.

Comment: the 3 is actually expected to be the number of columns grouped together. so those on their own would be 6 columns. so 3 columns grouped together would be [one, two, three], [four, five, six]. 2 would then split the 6 columns to be two in each column.

Comment: And what happens if the input has a number of columns that is not divisible by 3? You really haven't provided much information here. Please share your code and maybe we can help.

Comment: It's not expected to be a long or difficult code, I just feel like I'm having a brain fart. Also, pardon my chunk of code. I don't know how to put it in a code box as a comment.

Comment: This is quite simple. You have to split string into parts and then to "group" them into "columns".

Comment: You provided code... but no implementation of `convert`. You wrote no code for this method so far? I'm glad to help, but I don't intend to write it all for you.

Comment: @JeffTench Please don't put code in comments. It's unreadable and no body will ever find it anyway. You can add it to your question.

Comment: @dman2306, I don't expect anyone to write it all for me, just a push in the right direction. I'm drawing a blank with this.

Comment: Start by splitting on each comma. That will give you the individual values. Then surround them with [] for every multiple of three. That's really all I can say without a better description of what you're trying to accomplish and some sample code to show you've at least tried to solve this. This should be about 10 lines of code if that. I've got to be honest, this smells of a homework assignment type question to me... I mean aside from having a `convert` function call that doesn't exist, your C# syntax isn't even correct, so when you say it "doesn't work"... it won't even compile!

Comment: As I said, provide what you've tried as far as implementing `convert`. Yes, you included code, but saying `var result = solveProblem(input)` really doesn't show you've tried anything. Your code simply reads two values from two textboxes, it doesn't demonstrate any attempt to solve the problem unless you show what you've put inside `convert`. On top of that, as I said, your code doesn't even compile. Since you're the one who is going to get the job for solving this, not me, I feel like you should be doing more of the work... your potential employer wants to know you can solve this, not me.

Answer (score 1):

This code might give you a hint;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert("one,two,three,four,five,six,seven", 3)); 
    }

    public static string Convert(string inputString, int columnCount)
    {
        var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var entries = inputString.Split(',');
        var currentCol = 0;

        inputString = inputString.Replace(", ", ",");

        while (currentCol * columnCount < entries.Length)
        {
            var columnEntries = entries.Skip(currentCol * columnCount).Take(columnCount);
            var columnEntriesString = string.Join(", ", columnEntries);
            resultBuilder.Append($"[{columnEntriesString}],");
            currentCol++;
        }
        return resultBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(' ',',');
    }
```

Comment: Worth +1 even if your solution does not provide error handling.

Comment: Thank you Frode. I'm still have trouble understanding this, but that's okay. I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually. It is much appreciated.